# How to insert same image multiple time in HTML parent tag with DOM in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert same image 3 times in my HTML `</p>` tag with help of Javascript. Like below

```
<p class="image flex">
    <img
        src="images/Heart.png"
        alt="character image"
        class="images img"
    />
    <img
        src="images/Heart.png"
        alt="character image"
        class="images img"
    />
    <img
        src="images/Heart.png"
        alt="character image"
        class="images img"
    />
</p>
```

And to add this in JavaScript I used this code.

```
const img = document.querySelector('.image');
const image = new Image();
image.src = "images/Heart.png";
image.alt = 'character img';
image.classList.add('images', 'img');

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    img.appendChild(image);
}
```

this code is giving output only like these.

```
<p class="image flex">
    <img
        src="images/Heart.png"
        alt="character img"
        class="images img"
    />
</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only created the element once. Such that you append the same element three times in the same parent, which basically does nothing but waste CPU resources in this context.

Realistically, based on MDN and thanks to @araraonline pointing this out

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document,
>   appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position
>   (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node
>   before appending it to some other node).
>
> This means that a node can't be in two points of the document
>   simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first
>   removed, then appended at the new position.

What you should do is create the element inside the loop.

```
const img = document.querySelector('.image');

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const image = new Image()
  image.src = "images/Heart.png";
  image.alt = 'character img';
  image.classList.add('images', 'img');
  img.appendChild(image);
}
```

Comment: As an extra, the first two paragraphs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) explain the `appendChild` method nicely.

Comment: @araraonline That is definitely useful information. I shall add it

Comment: Ohh thank you, I miss understood the concept. thanks for the help guys @AbanaClara